# How to set textView when two items have been selected by using two spinners?

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my app I am using two spinners, so for the first spinner I select, lets say, village A and the second spinner village B.  Then I would like to display the distance and time it would take between those selected values:

Here is my code:

```
Spinner spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner spin2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.start_location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.end_location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (spin1.equals("Village A")) {
            if (spin2.equals("Village B")) {
                start.setText("60 Miles");
                time.setText("3 Hours");

            } else if (spin2.equals("Village A")) {
                //Etc...
            }
        } else if (spin1.equals("Village C")) {

        }
            //Etc...
        }
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  // Do nothing.
 }

  }
```

And:

```
<string-array name="start_location">
    <item>Village A</item>
    <item>Village B</item>
    <item>Village C</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="end_location">
    <item>Village A</item>
    <item>Village B</item>
    <item>Village C</item>
</string-array>
```

Sorry if it is a stupid question, but is the first time working with spinners.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide OnItemSelectedListener to each of the spinners and then you can override onItemSelected method and write your own logic

```
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {

                //Your logic
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Similarly you can write for another spinner spin2